# Finding common element in two arrays with best performing method

Tags: java, arrays

Implement a method that checks whether an integer is present in both integer array parameter 1 and integer array parameter 2 and prints the result of the search, with the best performance you can. The method parameters are: (1) the first integer array and (2) the second integer array of the same size as parameter 1 and (3) the integer to search for.

Note - Consider better performance to mean that a better performing method requires fewer general work steps to solve the problem with the same size of arrays. You may want to review the Java SE API page for java.util.Arrays

I was able to implement the solution but I am not sure if it the best-performing one because I am not using any java.util.Arrays methods as I am not sure which one to use necessarily to get me the best answer

```
public static void findCommonElements(int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int num){

        for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){

                if(arr1[i] == arr2[j] && arr1[i] == num){

                    System.out.println(num);

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I was able to update the code with following solution which completely removes for loop and implements binary for better performance

```
int[] arr1 = {7,8,5,1,2,3,6,7};
int[] arr2 = {9,8,6,4,1,2,4,5};
Arrays.sort(arr1);
Arrays.sort(arr2);

int index1 = Arrays.binarySearch(arr1, 5);
int index2 = Arrays.binarySearch(arr2, 5);
System.out.println(index1);
System.out.println(index2);

if(index1 < 0 || index2 < 0){
    System.out.println("number not found in both arrays");
}
else{
    System.out.println("number found in both arrays");
}
```

Comment: Your code has very bad performance. Iterate the 2 arrays in *independent* loops (not nested loops), setting 2 separate boolean for whether the array contained the given value. Then check if both booleans are `true`.

Comment: @Andreas but that would cause the scope error so for example if i find a common element for a particular index how would i keep it stored and check it within another loop. I guess i will need to create a third array with common boolean values with num if they match then i print the value. i will need 3 loops in that case

Comment: What do you mean *"common element for a particular index"*? Why would it cause scope error? --- You define a boolean, e.g. `boolean foundInArray1 = false`, then iterate the first array and set the boolean to `true` in the given number is found. Do the same for the second array.

Comment: Just do a linear search for both of them

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Question doesn't say that given value has to be found at same index. Solution is just to scan each independently, then do `if (foundInArray1 && foundInArray2)` to check if the value was found in both. Your links are not on point.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash those links don't help because we have to use arrays and not arrayList, thank you though I will keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: @Andreas you are right, I should have read the question more closely. Sorry for any inconvenience I might have caused. Thank you for making me understand the question more closely.

Comment: @Andreas Let me know if the updated code is good and better performing.

Comment: @JaZZyCooL Sort is _O(n log n)_, while a **simple sequential search** is _O(n)_, and hence faster, so that is certainly not the correct solution. My [very first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62520851/finding-common-element-in-two-arrays-with-best-performing-method?noredirect=1#comment110566886_62520851) told you to do *independent* search loops (1 hr 20 min ago). You now have 2 answers, and a total of 3 comments (4 with this one) saying so. Hope you are finally beginning to get it.

Comment: @Andreas Apparently accordig to the Note in the questions better performing answer is the one that works with fewer steps and not timing. So according to the question we have to implement a solution with fewer steps and not necessarily faster time. Which makes sense because this is an intro to java class and not data structures and algorithm class.

Comment: @JaZZyCooL Then [answer by Alex Rudenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522004/5221149) is the fewest steps, but it assumes you've learned about [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) yet.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah we haven't dealth with streams just yet so can't implement his solution. Thank you for the help though :) I am just going to stick with binary search for now and see if that worksout of not.

Comment: But, I believe you're misunderstanding. Fewest steps does not mean least code. E.g. a single loop that iterates 1000 times, is one line of code, but executes 1000 steps. If 10 lines of code could do the same job without any loops, then it would be 10 lines of code, and only 10 steps. In that example, more code is better.

Comment: @Andreas true that I guess I am misunderstanding the question but as John Billinger mentioned in his answer below that the question asks about implementing method from Java.util.Arrays which doesn't necessarily help in reducing the time and if I use two loops independently that does reduce the time, but doesn't necessarily implement Java.util.Arrays methods. I guess I can implement both solutions one in comments and one actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem description is a bit hard to follow, but by reference to the example code, I take this to be a fair rewording: "Write the best-performing method you can that takes two `int` arrays of the same length and a scalar `int` value `i` as parameters, and prints whether the value of `i` appears in both arrays."

Your first solution tests each pair of elements drawn one from the first array and the other from the second to determine whether they are equal to each other and to the target value. This is grossly inefficient for the problem as interpreted.

Your second solution sorts the arrays first, so as to be able to use a binary search to try to find the target element.  This is better, but still inefficient.  Although the binary searches are quite fast, the sorting required to prepare for them takes a lot more work than is saved by a single binary search.

Since it is sufficient to determine only whether the target value appears in both arrays, you can

- scan each array for the target value, once, independently of the other.
- skip the second scan if the first one does not find the target value
- break early from each scan when the target value is found

The latter two are minor improvements, as they reduce only the minimum and average number of steps.  The first, however, is a huge improvement, especially as array size increases,   because for arrays of length *n*, then this requires a number of steps proportional to *n* in the worst case, whereas your first example code requires steps proportional to *n*<sup>2</sup> in both the average and worst cases, and your second requires time proportional to *n* log *n* in the average and worst cases.

The implementation is left as the exercise it is intended to be.  However, with respect to

> I was able to implement the solution but I am not sure if it the
> best-performing one because I am not using any java.util.Arrays
> methods as I am not sure which one to use necessarily to get me the
> best answer

, I don't think `java.util.Arrays` offers any method that particularly helps with this problem, especially given the orientation toward best possible performance.

Comment: Yes thank you for clearing that up let me know if my updated code is better performing. I completely removed the for loops and instead implemented the binarysearch method to find the answer

Comment: @JaZZyCooL, I have updated the answer to address your updated question.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I guess according to the question better-performing means the one that requires fewer steps to implement and not necessarily faster time.

Comment: @JaZZyCooL, "best performing" does not mean "shortest code" to anyone.  The "fewer steps to solve the problem" surely means that *the program* performs fewer steps when it runs, as measured, for example, by counting operations evaluated (additions, comparisons, assignments, etc.).

Comment: true that might be the case but we haven't been taught data strucutures and algorithms just yet which means dealing with big O notation which is what is required in evaluating the timing I am guessing and thus since we haven't been taught about the same I am guessing the shorter code. I might be wrong

Comment: @JaZZyCooL, if you are uncertain about the requirements of the assignment then do, by all means, clarify them with your instructor.  I have absolute confidence, however, that they will confirm my interpration.  Aside from the general principles involved, note that it is fewer work steps "*for the same size of arrays*" that is the metric.  Source code length does not depend on the length of the input arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use search the arrays using streams:

```
public static boolean findCommonElements(int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int num) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr1).anyMatch(x -> x == num) &&
           Arrays.stream(arr2).anyMatch(x -> x == num);
}
```

Similar method using linear search in arrays of `Integer` using `Arrays.asList` to convert arrays:

```
public static boolean findCommonElements(Integer[] arr1, Integer[] arr2, int num) {
    return Arrays.asList(arr1).indexOf(num) > -1 &&
           Arrays.asList(arr2).indexOf(num) > -1;
}
```